# Not getting grep with a variable

Tags: shell-script, grep, pipe

I am assigning a variable to echo command which generates a random number.

For eg: `n=$(echo $(( (RANDOM%6) +1))`. I have to grep this variable in `/etc/passwd`.

So, my syntax reads like:

```
n=$(echo $(( (RANDOM%6) +1)) | grep "$n" /etc/passwd
```

But I get the entire file content(`/etc/passwd`) as output. I do not know where the syntax is wrong.

It is important I get the output in one line only.

Comment: Hint 1: Count your parentheses. Hint 2: The `$(echo` part is pointless; `n=$(( (RANDOM%6) +1))` is sufficient. Hint 3: A pipe `|` creates child processes that run essentially in parallel. Do you think it makes sense to execute these two commands in parallel?

Comment: Replace `|` by `;`.

Answer (score 1):

I notice your separating two commands that run in sequence and not sharing Io with a pipe rather than a semicolon.
Try

```
n=$(echo $(( (RANDOM%6) +1)) ; grep "$n" /etc/passwd
```

Comment: The `echo` is still pointless.

Comment: `grep -F "$((RANDOM%6+1))" /etc/passwd` but `(RANDOM%6)+1` == `RANDOM%7`

Answer (score 0):

> For eg: `n=$(echo $(( (RANDOM%6) +1))`. I have to grep this variable in `/etc/passwd`.

So you're trying to print all lines of `/etc/passwd` that contain a random number from one to six?

Wouldn't that just be (assuming `bash` or `zsh` or `ksh` for `$RANDOM`, which the base POSIX shell does *not* support):

```
grep $((RANDOM%6+1)) /etc/passwd
```

If you need that random number elsewhere:

```
n=$((RANDOM%6+1))
grep $n /etc/passwd
```

I don't think this is what you're trying to do, but you've oversimplified your question and lost that intent.